# Negative number comparison error

Tags: r

I have a problem for below comparison in R dataframe

```
if ((RSI<=40) & ((BUY_FACTOR>=-.5) || (BUY_FACTOR<=.5))){
    BUY_CONDITION<-"TRUE"
}
```

It works fine for BUY_FACTOR positive numbers but if it negative it just evaluates 1st condition and gives true instead of giving false like if BUY_FACTOR value is -1.12 and RSI is 38 it returns true instead of false

Comment: Your `BUY_FACTOR` conditions are joined by an `OR` operator, so they return TRUE if *either* is TRUE. So if `BUY_FACTOR <- -1.12`, `then BUY_FACTOR <= 0.5` is TRUE and the whole `OR` statement is TRUE. If you want to check that `BUY_FACTOR` is between `0.5` and `-0.5`, then you want to replace `||` with `&`

Comment: `(BUY_FACTOR>=-.5) || (BUY_FACTOR<=.5)` is true for all numbers

Comment: Thanks so much for help it work just did a basic mistake